# Android Textwatcher java.lang.NullPointerException error. Unable to initialize event listener

Tags: android, events, android-edittext, listener

I'm trying to use a TextWatcher with an EditText in my activity. I've written the class for the listener, my code compiles without error.

But at run time it crashes when I attempt to add the listener to the EditText. Giving a nullPointerException. I believe I've narrowed the error down to this line:

```
    fatherBox.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher());
```

I really can't see any errors with my code, the EditText does exist. I'm even starting to wonder if its a problem with Android Studio.

On create method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_clutch);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    EditText        fatherBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clutch_father_box);
    fatherBox.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher());

//end on create
}
```

Listener object:

```
private class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Activity snippet

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@id/clutch_father_box"
    android:layout_below="@id/clutch_temp_box"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/clutch_temp_box" />
```

Comment: the layout activity_new_clutch probably doesn't contain an EditText with an id of clutch_father_box.  Can you double check?  Maybe post your layout code?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated. The EditText can be found in the activity. I've added a snipped from the xml activity.

Comment: No sorry that didn't work either. My problem is with a new instance of the event listener. there is nothing wrong with my EditText or the variable I create.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working just fine.  it *has* to be your EditText object.  There's no other object in that line you specified that can even *be* null.
My java

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clutch_father_box);
        text.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher());
    }

    private class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // No implementation
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // No implementation
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/clutch_father_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Are you SURE you're edittext field is in the **Activity's** layout file?  are you sure its not in that `PlaceholderFragment`'s layout?

**Please** double check to make sure the EditText object is not null.  Try pasting the following snippet after grabbing the reference and before registering the listener

```
if (fatherBox == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "I really am null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Edit**

In the `PlaceHolderFragment` class, override `onCreateView` and work with the EditText field there.  i.e.

```
public class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText fatherBox;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place_holder, null, false);

        fatherBox = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clutch_father_box);
        fatherBox.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher());

        return rootview;
    }

    private class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // No Implementation
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
            // No Implementation
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The EditText exist in the fragment layout. So does that mean I'm initialising the textWatcher in the wrong life cycle method? I'm thinking a callback interface between the activity and the fragment is the wrong direction to be going in?

Comment: If the edittext exists in the Fragment Layout then that means the Fragment Class, that inflates the layout (i.e. PlaceHolderFragment) (NOT the activity class) must be the class that handles instantiating the EditText and registering the listener.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant by the wrong life cycle method. I can't really see anything in the documentation. 'onCreateView wouldn't be correct. What about 'onActivityCreated'?